# Merge 2 or more results together?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

See the following SQL:

```
SELECT M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date FROM com_result
   LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result.member_id 
GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result.member_id  Order By status_date DESC
```

This will show total numbers of records base on `DATE` and `member_id`

Example Result:

```
+----------+-------+------------+
| username | Total | DATE       |
+----------+-------+------------+
| bx7      |     3 | 2012-09-10 |
| bx2      |    25 | 2012-09-04 |
| bx2      |   401 | 2012-09-03 |
| bx1      |   703 | 2012-09-02 |
| bx4      |  1075 | 2012-09-02 |
+----------+-------+------------+
```

It work well, now I want to merge/union to another same and its same table structure.  **Second SQL:**

```
SELECT M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date FROM com_result_b
   LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result_b.member_id 
GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result_b.member_id  Order By status_date DESC
```

Assume the result from `com_result` would be:

```
| bx2   |    25 | 2012-09-04 |
```

And the result from `com_result_b` would be:

```
 | bx2   |    50 | 2012-09-04 |
```

So when it merged/union - I want the result be like:

```
 | bx2   |    75 | 2012-09-04 |
```

As you can see the value of `Total` increased from same Date from two tables. How can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a SUM

```
select username,SUM(Total) , DATE
(
    SELECT M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date FROM com_result_b 
       LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result.member_id  
    GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result.member_id  
   UNION ALL
   SELECT M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date FROM com_result_b   
      LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result_b.member_id    
   GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result_b.member_id 
) v

group by username, date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  username,
  IF(q1.Total IS NULL,0,q1.Total)+IF(q2.Total IS NULL,0,q2.Total) AS Total,
  q1.Date
FROM (
  SELECT member_id, M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date 
  FROM com_result
  LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result.member_id 
  GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result.member_id  
) AS q1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT member_id, M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date 
  FROM com_result_b
  LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result_b.member_id 
  GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result_b.member_id
) AS q2 ON q1.member_id=q2.member_id AND q1.Date=q2.Date
ORDER BY q1.Date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, why is your look a bit more complex than other answer?

Comment: Because I tried to catch all possible NULL-cases and still avoid a UNION. I am no friend of UNION on MySQL if it can be helped

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT X.username, SUM(X.Total)  AS TOTAL , X.Date
FROM( SELECT ... FROM com_result Union Select .. From com_result_b)X
GROUP BY X.username,  X.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

The simplest way to do is:

You just need to put both result in a derived table with a union all operator

```
 SELECT username,SUM(Total),Date
FROM   (
        SELECT M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date 
        FROM com_result
        LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result.member_id 
        GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result.member_id   
        union all
        SELECT M.username, count(*) as Total, date(status_date) as Date 
        FROM com_result_b
        LEFT JOIN members as M on M.member_id = com_result_b.member_id 
        GROUP BY date(status_date), com_result_b.member_id )a
GROUP BY username,Date
ORDER BY Date DESC
```